# Cronjob only on Saturday of first Thursday of the month

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I want a cronjob to run only on Saturday of the first Thursday of the month. So the first Thursday of the month it will run on Saturday.

If I wanna run it at 12 on the first Thursday of the month, I know I can do this.

```
0 12 * * 4 [ $(date +\%d) -le 7 ] && command
```

However I am not sure where to go from here, and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Do you mean "the Saturday after the first Thursday of the month?"

Comment: If it doesn't have to be cron, [Dianne Skoll's remind](https://dianne.skoll.ca/projects/remind/) can run programs based on dates calculated that way.

Answer (score 2):

The crontab does not have an OR condition, but you can simulate it with two lines:

```
0 12 1-7 * * test $(date +\%u) -eq 4 && command
0 12 * * sat command
```

Or just make a test condition smart enough:

```
0 12 * * * test ( $(date +\%u) -eq 4 -a $(date +\%d) -le 7 ) -o ( $(date +\%u) -eq 6 ) && command
```

Comment: Maybe: `0 12 * * * case "$(date +'%d%u')" in 0[3456789]6) command;; esac`

Comment: It seems to me that what the OP meant was: "the Saturday **after** the first Thursday of the month"